# Update every row with auto-generated value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, dml

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "person" (
    "ID" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
)
```

Data:

id name
1 monica
2 null
3 null
4 stephan
5 null

I need update null values with value "person" and auto incremented value (from 1 - person1, person2, person3 etc):

```
1 monica 
2 person1
3 person2
4 stephan
5 person3
```

What sql (oracle) query should I use?

Comment: Could you please provide more detail about your table structure? ex. provide a CREATE TABLE script that shows us the column names and data types etc.

Comment: Is there any other column to order this column?

Comment: By the way, not a good idea to name a table `"person"` (in double quotes). `person` (without quotes) will be a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytic function is not needed. The update can be done simply like this:

```
UPDATE person
   SET NAME = 'person' || ROWNUM
 WHERE name IS NULL;
```

#### Update

Since the person number needs to be sequential with the IDs of the person, this query can be used:

```
UPDATE person p
   SET p.name =
              'person'
           || (SELECT person_number
                 FROM (SELECT p2.id, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY p2.id) AS person_number
                         FROM person p2
                        WHERE name IS NULL)
                WHERE id = p.id)
 WHERE p.name IS NULL;
```

Comment: If my answer successfully answered your question, please mark the answer as the correct answer so others will not continue to submit answers.

Comment: unfortunately I just realized that it doesn't work correctly, sometimes row with lover id has bigger number, something like this.  1 monica 
2 person1
3 person3
4 stephan
5 person2

Comment: the problem is when I do: select id, rownum from person order by id, then rownum is not in order(id1, rownum3 , id2 rownum2 etc)

Comment: Just added an update that should correct your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have 2 issues, although your question only addresses 1 of them. You must not only 'fix the data' but also 'fix the system'. With the second (unaddressed) being the most important.  There are 2 methods for this, lets call them

1. the correct method

```
-- update existing data
update person1
   set name = 'PERSON' || to_char(rownum,'FM999') 
 where id is null;

-- fix the system
alter table person modify name not null;
```

2. the band-aid method

```
-- prepare for long term bandaid 
create sequence unknown_person_seq;

-- update existing data
update person
   set name = 'PERSON' || to_char(unknown_person_seq.nextval, 'FM99')
 where name is null;
select * from person2; 

-- adjust the system
alter table person modify name default 'Person' || to_char(unknown_person_seq.nextval, 'FM99');
```

The difference being the correct method keeps further data corruption out of the system. See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c05fb6cf97cfd9c988899f21499de8c6). It is far better to raise an exception for invalid data than it is to allow or generate bogus data. Consider your Person table holds customer information and you refer to them as PERSON4. How long will they remain your customer?

Comment: Doesn't matter if customer will be deleted. This is just auto-generated unique name to avoid Null. From this moment is not-null field, I just need fill nulls

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
SET
    name = (
    SELECT n
    FROM(
        SELECT
            id, 'person' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS n
        FROM
            person
                WHERE
            name IS NULL
        )u
    WHERE
        u.id = person.id)
        WHERE
    NAME IS NULL
```